# Closing a pop-up

Tags: python, popup, ui-automation

I am on a Windows machine trying to write a script so when Microsoft Word asks for a password it just exists out of the pop up window and out of Microsoft Word. I need some way to recognize that it is asking for a password.

Is this possible?

Comment: No, not in python. If you were using Java, perhaps. I could be wrong though

Answer (score 0):

[pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/) can detect any dialog window. After getting started just read [about find_windows function](https://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg/pywinauto/docs/code/pywinauto.findwindows.html).

Comment: If you need to use clean Python (for example, on many machines), you can import pywinauto from local subfolder like user-written package. Of course, you need to make a copy of pywinauto folder on each machine. But we do that for our daily work, it's not a big problem I think. Also we do fixes inside `pywinauto` and have that code under versions control.